# PhoneGap Android application closes and The page at file://.. error

Tags: android, cordova

My application works fine in emulator, but when I put it on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy Spica) I get error: `The page at file:// says: gap:["Device","getDeviceInfo","Device0",true]`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("test1");
    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body onload="deviceReady()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("test2");
        function deviceReady() {
            alert("Ready"); 
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get all alerts. I found out that `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` is not working on android device. 
And there is another problem. When I click 'ok' or 'cancel' on `The page at file://...` error, application closes in 5 seconds. What seems to be the problem?

*I use Dreamweaver CS5.5 to build application. Maybe there is a problem..
* and it's phonegap 1.0.0

DEBUG:

```
D/PhoneGapLog( 8235): file:///android_asset/www/javascript/phonegap.js: Line 624 : Error: SyntaxError: Parse error

I/Web Console( 8235): Error: SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///android_asset/www/javascript/phonegap.js:624
```

---- This is when app closes ----

```
I/WindowManager( 2163): WIN DEATH: Window{461efdd8 com.app.mobile/com.app.mobile.DefaultActivity paused=false}

I/ActivityManager( 2163): Process com.app.mobile (pid 8235) has died.
```

Comment: Can you post the exception/error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cordova-2.0.0.js this javascript lib for your code

and add below code in your js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Working properly");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use latest phonegap version 1.9.0 OR 2.1.0

onDeviceReady event should work.